Dual of a semi definite program not in primal form
I want to find the dual SDP of the following SDP (let's call it $P$) (see Problem 1):
$\min x$
subject to:
$\begin{bmatrix} 
x & 1 \\ 
1 & y 
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 $ (that is, it is positive semidefinite)
I am aware of the following the definition of an SDP and its dual
Primal SDP:
$\min Tr(CX)$
subject to:
$Tr(A_iX) = b_i, i = 1, \dots m$,
$X \succeq 0$ (that is, $X$ is positive semidefinite).
Its dual SDP:
$\max b^Ty$
subject to:
$\sum_{i=1}^m A_i y_i \preceq C$.
Now, $P$ (as defined in the beginning of this post) is not in primal form. The approach I have taken is to construct an equivalent SDP as follows (say, $P^\prime$).
$\min x$
subject to:
$Tr( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0.5 \\ 0.5 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x & w \\ w & y \end{bmatrix}) = 1 $
$\begin{bmatrix} x & w \\ w & y \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$
and then simply compute the dual of $P^\prime$ using the above definitions and declare it to be the dual of $P$.
Is this a correct approach? In particular, to compute the dual of an SDP do we always need to convert it to primal form?

Simply define a matrix variable
$X := \begin{bmatrix} 
x & 1 \\ 
1 & y 
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$
while the coefficient matrix in the objective is
$C = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

I do not think that in the definition of a semidefinite program we are allowed to define the matrix variable as anything other than where all the entries are a variable

We can & the transformation is straightforward
$X := \begin{bmatrix}
x & x_2 \
x_2 & x_3
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$, and add constraints $Tr(C_2X)=1$ and $Tr(C_3X)=y$. Alternatively, you can also think the problem is given in the standard dual form.
